# Column does not exist in PostgreSQL DB

Tags: python, database, postgresql, view

> Returns:
>         A list of tuples, each of which contains (id, name, wins, matches):
>           id: the player's unique id (assigned by the database)
>           name: the player's full name (as registered)
>           wins: the number of matches the player has won
>           matches: the number of matches the player has played

my sql script is the following:

```
--if the DB already exists drop it so i can create it again
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS tournament; 
--create DB and connect to it
CREATE DATABASE tournament;
\c tournament;
--create table for players
CREATE TABLE players (
    id SERIAL, 
    name TEXT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
); 
--create table for matches
CREATE TABLE matches (
    id_match SERIAL, 
    id_winner INTEGER NULL REFERENCES players(id),
    id_looser INTEGER NULL REFERENCES players(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_match)
);
--create the view to count all the wins of a player
CREATE VIEW countWins AS
    SELECT players.id AS ID,players.name AS Name,coalesce(count(matches.id_winner),0) as Record
    FROM players, matches WHERE players.id = matches.id_winner
    GROUP BY players.id;
--create the view for all the matches a players has played
CREATE VIEW countMatches AS
    SELECT players.id AS ID,players.name AS Name,count(*) AS Played
    FROM players, matches WHERE players.id = matches.id_winner OR players.id = matches.id_looser
    GROUP BY players.id;
--
CREATE VIEW standings AS
    SELECT countMatches.ID,countMatches.Name,coalesce(countWins.Record,0) AS wins,countMatches.Played
    FROM countMatches LEFT JOIN countWins
    ON countWins.ID = countMatches.ID or wins = 0
    ORDER BY wins DESC;
```

when I run the

> \i tournament.sql

in the command line I get this error:

```
DROP DATABASE
CREATE DATABASE
You are now connected to database "tournament" as user "vagrant".
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE VIEW
CREATE VIEW
psql:tournament.sql:42: ERROR:  column "wins" does not exist
LINE 4:  ON countWins.ID = countMatches.ID or wins = 0
```

I don't understand why is saying column wins does not exist if I'm creating it on "standings" view...

Comment: `... AS wins, ...` The wins is not a column, just an alias. You cannot refer to that in the where clause (or ON clause). Either use the complete expression, or push the whole thing into a subquery.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply.. could you please show me how to fix that?@wildplasser

Comment: `ORDER BY wins DESC;` -->> `ORDER BY 3 DESC;` will probably do the trick. #quickhack

Comment: I'm getting the same error even after replace it for ORDER BY 3 DESC; @wildplasser